# Accessing file content as a resource using Spring Cloud config server

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-config-server

Our application setup includes having a centralized configuration server using **Spring Cloud Config Server**. The config server reads property files from a folder `config-repo` placed in its local file system, and exposes them as configurations.

Other microservices then access these configurations using SpEL or any other means. Note that both the config-server and the microservice run on two separate physical machines.

For e.g., config-repo/application.properties file has a property:

```
sftp.host=localhost
```

Other applications access this property using:

```
@Value("${sftp.host}")
private String sftpHost;
```

My problem now is that, I would like to access a text(specifically a private key) provided in one of the files in the config-repo as a `org.springframework.core.io.Resource` in my microservices. So if I have a file `config-repo/private-key.txt` containing the private key, I would like to access it in my microservice using:

```
@Value("???")
private Resource sftpPrivateKey;
```

I don't think I cannot use `classpath:` prefix here(the file is not present in the the microservice classpath) nor can I use `file:` prefix (since the file is not present on the server on which the microservice is running). How can I correctly initialize `sftpPrivateKey` using the file placed on the config server?

Comment: `http(s)...` is also a valid "spring resource" protocol/schema (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/UrlResource.html) (i only hope it's not a public repo/url:) ..so if you have/know an (available) "url" for `private-key.txt`, try that!

Comment: Thanks for your response. There is no URL available for the file currently. The file just gets deployed along with other configurations on the server.